# Upload files to a specific folder in dropbox

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I was using this example to upload files to dropbox:

> https://github.com/geersch/DropboxRESTApi/blob/master/src/part-5/README.md

Which is:

```
public FileSystemInfo UploadFile(string root, string path, string file)
{
  //...
}
```

> The method has 3 parameters:
>
> **root:** The root relative to which the path is specified. Valid values
> are sandbox and dropbox.
> **path:** The path to the file you want to
> upload.
> **file:** Absolute path to the local file you want to upload
>
> *Call this method as follows:*

```
var file = api.UploadFile("dropbox", "photo.jpg", @"C:\Pictures\photo.jpg");
```

Dropbox API says exactly the same as the example:

> https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-POST

So no mentioning of "parent folder"..
How can I upload files under a specific folder instead of the root?

Comment: You're pointing to the post method. I think you might want to take a look at `files_put`. I also think that the `path` parameter includes the folder part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cant you just do

```
var file = api.UploadFile("dropbox", @"myfolder\photo.jpg", @"C:\Pictures\photo.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
I use this method for combining paths as the target directory

```
public static string CombinePath(string folder, string filename) => folder == "/" ? $"/{filename}" : $"{folder}/{filename}";
```

If you need to upload your file into the root directory the only parameter is `/` to identify the root.