# Is it possible to upload a file to Dropbox API v2.0 with a path?

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm successfully uploading a new document by specifying its name and its content but is that possible to actually pass the document itself?

```
async Task Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file, string content)
{
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
    {
        var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
            folder + "/" + file,
            WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
            body: mem);

        Console.WriteLine("Saved {0}/{1} rev {2}", folder, file, updated.Rev);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it yes:

    var file = api.UploadFile("dropbox", "photo.jpg", @"C:\Pictures\photo.jpg");  

More info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699031/upload-files-to-a-specific-folder-in-dropbox

Comment: Thank you, but I'm talking about the new Dropbox sdk for .net so this question is not relevant for me..

Comment: [Check the api sample, To upload a file:](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/06/introducing-a-preview-of-the-new-dropbox-net-sdk-for-api-v2/)

Comment: The code that I have posted above is from there.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Upload-a-file-with-a-given-path/m-p/196538#M9005 ]